# Jenkins publish over SSH error

Tags: jenkins

I'm expericing the following error when trying to use the Publish Over SSH plugin to jenkins when using a different key.

jenkins.plugins.publish_over.BapPublisherException: Failed to add SSH key. Message [invalid privatekey: TheKey]

I've tried different alternatives of using the path to key and the key field itself.

Has anyone experienced / solved this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If someone came across this type of error.

Jenkins "**Publish Over SSH plugin**" accept private key in  **OpenSSH format** format.

Please use below steps, to convert private key in  OpenSSH format.
Using Putty gen.

1. Open PuttyGen
2. Click Load
3. Load your private key (Enter passphrase if required)
4. Go to Conversions->Export OpenSSH and export your private key

Copy and paste the private key into the Key section of Jenkins SSH Server.
Enter Passphrase.

Click on "Test Configuration" button, "Success" :)

Comment: I had a .ppk file and PuttyGen helped me get the private key. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

In your path (to the key), do you have both public and private keys in this folder?

I think It's mandatory when you pair 2 machines.

Comment: Where do I identify the name of the public key?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a different key, you will have a public and private key pair. The public key has to be added to the target server `autorized_keys` file with in the `<$HOME user>/.ssh/` and the private key has to configured in the Jenkins either using the path to key and the key field itself.

Comment: Yes its added to the authorized keys. I think my error is I was using a ppk key instead of the pem key.